# Get bounding box for coordinates in columns of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, spatial, r-sf, bounding-box

I have a dataframe with two columns of type `numeric`.

```
foo <- data.frame(replicate(2,sample(10.1:15.2,100,rep=TRUE)))

    X1 X2
1 13.1 15.1
2 13.1 11.1
3 13.1 15.1
4 10.1 13.1
5 15.1 11.1
6 13.1 11.1
...
```

These numbers represent coordinates in `4326`. `X1` is latitude, `X2` is longitude. How would I get the bounding box for all these coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert to `sf` and use `st_bbox`:

```r
library(sf)

foo %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("X2","X1"), crs = 4326) %>% 
  st_bbox()

# xmin ymin xmax ymax 
# 10.1 10.1 15.1 15.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more succint using `sfheaders` if you want a light-weight option for using in a package.

```r
sfheaders::sf_bbox(foo, x = "X2", y = "X1")

# xmin ymin xmax ymax 
# 10.1 10.1 15.1 15.1 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "bbox"
```

But if you're using `sf` in your workflow anyway, then the pure `sf` approach is fine.